# Airplay Button is not showing in Player Controls with AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, airplay

I created a Video Player using AVPlayer and AVPlayerViewController. I have set "`allowsExternalPlayback`" property to true and also "`usesExternalPlaybackWhileExternalScreenIsActive`" property to true. But still I am not getting Airplay Icon in Player Controls.

```
player = AVPlayer(URL: url!)
player!.allowsExternalPlayback = true
player?.usesExternalPlaybackWhileExternalScreenIsActive = true
```

I am running my app on ios 9.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an MPVolumeView in order to get this. You can read about this here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AirPlayGuide/EnrichYourAppforAirPlay/EnrichYourAppforAirPlay.html

Answer (score 2):

```
func appleTv()
    {
        let rect = CGRect(x: -100, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
        let airplayVolume = MPVolumeView(frame: rect)
        airplayVolume.showsVolumeSlider = false
        self.view.addSubview(airplayVolume)
        for view: UIView in airplayVolume.subviews {
            if let button = view as? UIButton {
                button.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
                break
            }
        }
        airplayVolume.removeFromSuperview()
    }
```