# Swift AVPlayerViewController Add AirPlay

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, airplay, avplayerviewcontroller

I'm attempting to enable AirPlay with my `AVPlayerViewController`. In the document:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/avkit/avplayerviewcontroller

It states

> AVPlayerViewController automatically supports AirPlay, but you need to perform some project and audio session configuration before it can be enabled in your application.

Under the `Capabilities` tab, I did enable the Background Mode for Audio, AirPlay, and Picture in Picture. I have created the `AVPlayerViewController` as follows:

```
// Create the view controller and player
let moviePlayerViewController: AVPlayerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
let moviePlayer = AVPlayer(url: videoUrl!)

moviePlayer.allowsExternalPlayback = true
moviePlayer.usesExternalPlaybackWhileExternalScreenIsActive = true

// Initialize the AVPlayer
moviePlayerViewController.player = moviePlayer

// Present movie player and play when completion
self.present(moviePlayerViewController, animated: false, completion: {
    moviePlayerViewController.player?.play()
})
```

I thought the two lines

```
moviePlayer.allowsExternalPlayback = true
moviePlayer.usesExternalPlaybackWhileExternalScreenIsActive = true
```

Would add the AirPlay support but I'm wrong. I have read that AirPlay can be used by adding `MPVolumeView`, but that's for a custom video controller, not the built in one. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35771440/airplay-button-is-not-showing-in-player-controls-with-avplayer

Comment: The `MPVolumeView` is for custom video controllers, not the built in one.

Comment: Take a look at this https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AirPlayGuide/EnrichYourAppforAirPlay/EnrichYourAppforAirPlay.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011045-CH6-SW1

Comment: Do you find how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You should still be able to use `MPVolumeView`. Just use the following:

```
    let volumeView = MPVolumeView()
    self.view.addSubview(volumeView)
```

or if you just want the menu to show up, you can use:

```
    let volumeView = MPVolumeView(frame: CGRect(x: -100, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
    self.addSubview(volumeView)
    for view: UIView in volumeView.subviews {
        if let button = view as? UIButton {
            button.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
            volumeView.removeFromSuperview()
            break
        }
    }
```

This will put it outside of the current view and then trigger the action that displays the air play menu.

Comment: My plan is to share iPhone screen to any TV (Apple or samsung means airPlay supported devices). How i can implement this ?

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays you should have no problem doing this.

(1) Under the `Capabilities` tab, enable Background Mode for Audio

(2) With your

```
var ezPlayer: AVPlayerViewController!
```

just

```
    ezPlayer.showsPlaybackControls = true
    ezPlayer.player = AVPlayer(url: ... )

    ezPlayer.player!.allowsExternalPlayback = true
    ezPlayer.player!.usesExternalPlaybackWhileExternalScreenIsActive =
```

and you should be fine. Build to a device. Assuming you are on a usable wifi network with an apple TV, apple laptops, the airplay icon will appear and work.

There's no need to use an MPVolumeView these days.