# Airplay button not showing for VolumeView

Tags: ios, swift

I've implemented the volumeView class onto my app so that I can pick and output my audio via airplay however the button for this is not showing.

I don't get any compiler errors and after reading [Airplay Button is not showing in Player Controls with AVPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35771440/airplay-button-is-not-showing-in-player-controls-with-avplayer) I can't work out what I'm doing differently.

The code:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let volumeView = MPVolumeView(frame: myView.bounds);
    self.view.addSubview(volumeView);
    
    volumeView.showsRouteButton = true;
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red;
    volumeView.center = CGPoint(x:380, y:150)
```

Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you set the volume view's frame and position in that strange way? It makes no sense.

Comment: Bit of an IOS noob if I'm honest and just ended up with this after a series of trial and error. Can you suggest a more sensible alternative - I want the view in the top 25% of the screen, with the view centered. I did hace `volumeView.center = self.view.center` but this put it in the center of the whole screen.

Comment: My main query is about why the route button is not showing - any ideas as to why this might be?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that this isn't supposed to work any more. On my device, if you change to an AirPlay device using the control center, the MPVolumeView disappears completely.

So I would advise against use of MPVolumeView, except perhaps for the simplest cases. It is extremely old technology and hasn't worked as advertised for years. Properties like `showsRouteButton` and `areWirelessRoutesAvailable` were deprecated years ago.

The user can change routes using the control center, or you can present an AVRoutePickerView; and you can detect route changes with AVRouteDetector. So you really don't need this feature of MPVolumeView anyway.

Comment: I don't think I can use AVRoutePickerView as I can only go as high as 10.1 on my VM of xcode. I just want the base functionality to switch the media to my Airplay server. Do you think It's possible with such an old device, or am i better off finding a more up to date vm?